# How to create region in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

How can i create a region to my code in blazor?

I try this:

```cs
#region Test
 'code'
#endregion
```

And don't result i cannot "close" and "open" code in region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#region` code folding is currently not supported within Razor pages.

There is a known issue as posted [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-the-new-razor-editor-in-visual-studio-2022/#:%7E:text=%23region%20code%20folding). We therefor can assume that this will be catered for in a future update. I do not see it in the version 17.2 roadmap, so it might only happen at a later stage. Keep an eye on their GitHub.

Comment: Unfortunately now at v17.5.5 they still don't have it and there seem to be no one needing it because there is no Github issue or Feedback,.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Region` in normal code classes in Blazor.  Though not stated, I assume you are referring to Razor components.  These are Razor files, not C# class files, and the `Region` syntax does not exist.

If you want to use regions in the code in razor files, you can in code-behind partial classes.

Comment: Yes, i m referring Razor components

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a wrapper component? :-)

Wrapper component: CollapsibleRegion.razor (or whatever)

```
@if (@ChildContent is not null)
{
    @ChildContent
}
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent {get; set;}
}
```

to use:

```
<CollapsibleRegion> @* Some region *@
    <div ...>
</CollapsibleRegion>
```

This workaround works because the editor will collapse components. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this may be a solution, as for now:

```
@if ("#region My region name here" != "")
{
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
}
```